# Force FSCK on boot in yocto image

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I would like to enforce a filesystem check on my `bitbake`'d image. If I understand correctly I need to add `fsck=force` and `fsck.repair=yes` to `/proc/cmdline`. Is this approach correct? What is the right way to do modify `/proc/cmdline`?

EDIT: I ran `oe-pkgdata-util find-path /proc/cmdline` which exited with `ERROR: Unable to find any package producing path /proc/cmdline`. Thus, I speculate it is generated during kernel compilation. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**;tldr** add your stuff to `bootargs` variable in U-Boot

First of all, yes, your approach is correct - you need to pass two arguments `fsck=force` and `fsck.repair=yes` as boot arguments to your kernel while booting. But you are looking in the wrong direction. All this stuff is about booting and Linux kernel, not actually about Yocto or bitbake.

There are several ways to pass boot arguments to kernel, like

- hardcode into kernel code (brute-force option, you'll have to dig sources:) )
- use `CONFIG_CMDLINE` kernel config ([docs](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/CMDLINE.html) say bootloader args would be appended to it)
- pass arguments via bootloader (the most flexible and usable way)
- pass arguments by `.dtb`-file ([Device Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_tree#:%7E:text=In%20computing%2C%20a%20device%20tree,the%20buses%20and%20the%20peripherals.) Binary file, more of this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48801998/passing-bootargs-via-chosen-node-in-device-tree-not-working-for-beaglebone-black))
- invent something else, as Linux kernel is a DIY swiss-army-knife

Using `CONFIG_CMDLINE` is easy - just append your to this variable like

```
CONFIG_CMDLINE=" loglevel=3 fsck=force fsck.repair=yes"
```

more info about tweaking kernel configs in Yocto [here](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/kernel-dev/advanced.html#recipe-space-metadata).

**Best way** is to use bootloader to pass arguments to your kernel. In Yocto you are likely using U-Boot as bootloader, so `bootargs` environment variable (in U-Boot environment, NOT in linux userspace environment) is [what you need](https://www.denx.de/wiki/publish/DULG/to-delete/LinuxBootArgs.html).

First of all, try to search for file **uEnv.txt**. It may be found on main partition in the `/boot` folder, or on separate boot-partition. This file holds some additional configuration options for U-Boot. For example, there may be specified default console for kernel - option `console=...`. You can append your stuff somewhere there. Likely there would be specific option for adding boot arguments to the kernel. Inside U-Boot such option would be appended to `bootargs` during boot process.

If you found **uEnv.txt** on your device, than it should be somewhere around in Yocto. Search for BSP-meta-layer.

If there is no such file for your device, bad news - you'll have to dig some U-Boot code)) The command, that actually sets `bootargs` environment variable to appropriate value is this

```
env set bootargs ${bootargs} fsck=force fsck.repair=yes
```

U-Boot is packaged as single binary and written onto memory device (SDcard or whatever) by some offset. What is important here, during ordinary boot process you have no manual access to U-Boot - it is just loaded automagically, do some stuff and loads the kernel.

You can however connect to your device's default debug console (with UART likely) and enter the command manually there, but this boot sequence wouldn't be reproducible - next time device is booted, this command wouldn't be applied.

That's why you need to embed this command exactly into U-Boot source code - to apply command instantly, for every boot.

Inside U-Boot sources look for your device's configuration file. This should be `.h`-file (C header) with your board name as part of it's name and variables `BOOTENV_BOOTCOMMAND` and/or `BOOTENV` inside it. This variables define boot script for U-Boot. That is, boot sequence for specific device is constant - there should be no need for any manual interactions during boot. That is, during every boot U-Boot is doing pretty the same things. Exactly this things are hardcoded in `BOOTENV_BOOTCOMMAND` and/or `BOOTENV` in the form of long C-string with boot script for U-Boot (just like bash-script).

There you may add this command

```
env set bootargs ${bootargs} fsck=force fsck.repair=yes
```

or maybe you'll find `bootargs` definition itself, like `bootargs=...`, so add you arguments right there.

Also consider userspace utility `fsck`. You may configure **systemd** to trigger it on system startup and after that periodically on schedule. This is not actually what you wanted, but maybe this also would be appropriate for your case.

Comment: Thank you so much about the extensive explanation! Learned quite a bit from that!