# How to set Linux kernel command line on ARM?

Tags: command-line, linux-kernel, arm, embedded-linux, device-tree

My understanding is that for ARM there are three sources for the kernel boot command line in general:

1. Those given as CONFIG_CMDLINE in the kernel configuration
2. Those passed on by the boot loader (typically U-Boot on ARM processors)
3. Those included in the device tree, under chosen/bootargs
   Which one is used depends on kernel configuration parameters. My question is how to choose between these options using kernel configuration?

And can one append to another i.e. can we pass some using CONFIG_CMDLINE and then append hardware specific parameters in device tree?

I'm trying combination 1, 2 AND 3 to begin with but this doesn't compile:

```dts
/dts-v1/; 
#include "imx6q.dtsi"
#include "imx6q-h.dtsi"
#include "imx6q-m.dtsi"
/ {
    model = "A M";
    compatible = "a,imx6q-hydra13", "a,imx6q-mercury",
                    "a,imx6q-hydra", "fsl,imx6q";
};

&ssd_touch {
    status = "okay";
};

ERROR AT THIS LINE: chosen {  
        bootargs = "console=ttymxc1,115200";
};
```

Comment: how many combinations did you try and what were your results, please post the experiments and results

Comment: CONFIG_CMDLINE sets the default kernel command string.  Then there is a choice of these options: (1) CONFIG_CMDLINE_FROM_BOOTLOADER will use the command line from bootloader in preference to the the default kernel command string. (2) CONFIG_CMDLINE_EXTEND will append the command line from the bootloader to the default kernel command string. (3) CONFIG_CMDLINE_FORCE will only use the default kernel command string, ignoring any provided by the boot loader.

Comment: The error is probably because your `chosen` node is outside the root node.

Comment: @IanAbbott   Thank you. But where does the device tree fit in this scheme of things? I am using AOSP 9 code and set the command line in BoardConfig.mk file AND the device tree but I don't see the device tree command line showing up anywhere including /proc/cmdline.

Answer (score 5):

> My understanding is that for ARM there are three sources for the kernel boot command line in general:

That's not accurate for the Linux ARM kernel. The kernel only deals with two "sources", a `default kernel command` string and a `bootloader kernel arguments` string.
More details follow.

> My question is how to choose between these options using kernel configuration?

You choices may be limited by only *"using kernel configuration"*.

The "additional" command-line configuration choices, i.e. CONFIG_CMDLINE_FROM_BOOTLOADER ("Use `bootloader kernel arguments` if available"),  CONFIG_CMDLINE_EXTEND ("Extend `bootloader kernel arguments`"), and CONFIG_CMDLINE_FORCE ("Always use the `default kernel command` string") are only available (since version 3.7) when support for the old ATAGs  parameter passing (i.e. CONFIG_ATAGS) is enabled.
However CONFIG_ATAGS does default to `y` unless explicitly disabled. About a dozen **_defconfig** files in mainline **arch/arm/configs/** do explicitly disable this CONFIG_ATAGS.

---

> But where does the device tree fit in this scheme of things?

The Device Tree is the provider of `bootloader kernel arguments`.
That is, the `bootargs=` property in the `/chosen` node, is the conventional method of providing the command line to the ARM kernel, i.e. when CONFIG_ATAGS is disabled, or either CONFIG_CMDLINE_FROM_BOOTLOADER or CONFIG_CMDLINE_EXTEND are enabled.
The command line is retrieved by the kernel from the Device Tree as a string by **early_init_dt_scan_chosen()** in **drivers/of/fdt.c**

Only if CONFIG_CMDLINE_FORCE (with CONFIG_ATAGS) are enabled will the Device Tree `bootargs=` property be ignored.

You can configure/build the ARM kernel with a `default kernel command` using CONFIG_CMDLINE in case nothing else managed to set the command line.
A comment in **drivers/of/fdt.c** documents this.

CONFIG_CMDLINE_EXTEND (with CONFIG_ATAGS) results in a command line that is the concatenation of the Device Tree `bootargs=` property  with the contents of CONFIG_CMDLINE.

***However ...***

When using U-Boot to boot the Linux kernel, be aware that when the environment variable `bootargs` is defined, U-Boot will (try to) install that `bootargs` environment variable (as a property) into the the `/chosen` node of the loaded Device Tree blob.
If the `/chosen` node does not exist in the DT, then it is created.
If the `bootargs=` property does not exist in that DT node, then it is created.
If the `bootargs=` property already exists in that DT node, then it is overwritten with the U-Boot environment variable.
See **fdt_chosen()** in **common/fdt_support.c**.

IOW U-Boot's `bootargs` environment variable typically becomes the *de facto* kernel command line.

---

> And can one append to another i.e. can we pass some using CONFIG_CMDLINE and then append hardware specific parameters in device tree?

Only if (a) CONFIG_ATAGS is enabled, and (b) CONFIG_CMDLINE_EXTEND is enabled, and (c) ensure that there is no `bootargs` variable in U-Boot's environment.

---

***Bottom Line***

1. U-Boot always tries to pass its `bootargs` variable to the kernel using the Device Tree.
2. The `bootargs=` property in the Device Tree is always used by the kernel as the `bootloader kernel arguments` as mentioned in the **arch/arm/Kconfig** file.