# How does the linux kernel know about the initrd when booting with a device tree?

Tags: linux-kernel, bootloader, device-tree, arm-linux

I am writing a bootloader for my Arm board (32-bit i.MX6) and want to boot the Linux kernel using a device tree and an initrd file located at a static location in memory.

I looked to U-Boot as a reference and I see I can use the `bootm` command to provide a kernel, device tree and ramdisk:

```
Boot application image from memory:
        bootm [addr [arg ...]] - boot application image stored in memory passing arguments 'arg
        ...'; when booting a Linux kernel,‘arg' can be the address of an initrd image
```

I know there are two ways to pass information from a bootloader to the kernel, the legacy ATAGS method and the modern device tree method.

With ATAGS this can be achieved with the `ATAG_INITRD2` tag which describes the address that a ramdisk is stored in memory. However, with a flattened device tree no ATAGS are passed to the kernel (which is shown in the boot log with the "No ATAGs?" message). I do not see any method to specify a ramdisk when using a device tree.

If I look at the [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/arm/Booting) for booting the Linux kernel on Arm I see the following interface is specified:

```
- CPU register settings
  r0 = 0,
  r1 = machine type number discovered in (3) above.
  r2 = physical address of tagged list in system RAM, or
       physical address of device tree block (dtb) in system RAM
```

In fact, the same document states that an initramfs must be configured prior to booting, yet includes no details on how to do so when booting with a device tree.

Is there some alternative way to achieve this? Is the required information appended to the device tree automatically by U-Boot, or is there an alternative way to notify the kernel of the ramdisk location?

Comment: See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/devicetree/usage-model.html#runtime-configuration  Or you could use the `initrd` parameter passed via the kernel command line (which is also in the DT).  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68307458/how-to-set-linux-kernel-command-line-on-arm/68340492#68340492

Answer (score 1):

It will be patched in the dtree by the bootloader; e.g.

```
/ {
    chosen {
        linux,initrd-start = <0x....>;
        linux,initrd-end = <0x....>;
    };
```