# Detailed output during U-Boot Linux boot

Tags: linux-kernel, u-boot

I am debugging a DoA internet router and I need to get more information out of it, so I can narrow down the issue. I am connecting to it via RS232 and Putty. U-Boot seems to function properly as I can see it booting on the console and I can write commands and get a response. The problem comes when booting into Linux.

```
=> boot
Stopping PFE...
1 bytes read in 6 ms (0 Bytes/s)
12879571 bytes read in 991 ms (12.4 MiB/s)
13330 bytes read in 16 ms (813.5 KiB/s)
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 81000000
   Image Name:   Linux
   Image Type:   AArch64 Linux Kernel Image (gzip compressed)
   Data Size:    12879507 Bytes 12.3 MiB
   Load Address: 80080000
   Entry Point:  80080000
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 90000000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x90000000
   Uncompressing Kernel Image
   Using Device Tree in place at 0000000090000000, end 0000000090006411
WARNING: fdt fixup stdout: could not read serial0 alias: FDT ERR NOT FOUND
PCIe0: pcie@3400000 Root Complex: no link

Starting kernel...

System kernel started
System init started
System applications started

U-Boot R2.0 (Sep 08 2021 06:01:59)
SoC: LS1012AE Rev2.0 (0x87040020)
```

The device loads normally all the way until "System applications started" where the next step would be to log into the Linux environment. Instead it hangs there for ~30 seconds and reboots automatically.

How can I get more detailed information from the console about what it's doing during the last few steps?

I tried adding a "console = yes" in the environment variables but that didn't change anything.

What other useful diagnostics can I run inside U-Boot, like a memory checksum or some kind of auto diagnostic?

I tried looking through the list of environment variables to enable some sort of "detailed" log output but didn't find anything similar.

Comment: You need to inspect your kernel configuration, your Device Tree, and the U-Boot environment (i.e the **bootargs** environment variable) to determine what is in the kernel command line. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68307458/how-to-set-linux-kernel-command-line-on-arm/68340492#68340492

Comment: You need to find proper parameters to the `console`, also try to use `earlycon` instead. But this all requires knowledge about hardware. Yet, you may add `ignore_loglevel` to the kernel command line, but I believe the Linux kernel is simply build without `printk()` support and you won't see anything anyway.

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please delete this.