# is it possible to use uboot setenv command to set static IP address for the Ethernet port in Linux?

Tags: linux, yocto, u-boot

I can use the below line to set MAC address for the Ethernet port

**setenv ethaddr E4:1E:0A:10:12:33**

is it possible to use the same command  (setenv) to the set IP and the nesmask as well?

I know I can use **ifconfig** but with that after reboot or power cycle the configuration is lost.

thanks

I have searched everywhere but couldn't find the answer

update:
Apologies if I didn't explain the reason behind my question at the beginning. I am working on a custom board which runs Linux, most of the files system and configurations are write protected and not easy to modify once the device is powered up. some stuff like Ethernet MAC address could set up from the UBOOT environment. I only asked the question out of curiosity.
I can configure the Ethernet fully in systemd network manager and rebuild the whole firmware.

Comment: Setting the IP address in U-Boot will do nothing for you when Linux is booted.  Linux has to do its own setup of its IP address. See https://superuser.com/questions/502793/how-to-bring-network-up-at-boot-time-in-linux

Answer (score 0):

Please mention why you want to set ip/netmask/mac in the bootloader?

Once the linux is booted, you can set all these through command line or write it to a file. Eth ip/netmask/mac address/hw addr

Also after setting any variable in the bootloader,  did you save the environment?

`setenv variable-name value`

`saveenv`

Comment: I added an updated to my question. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

> I can use the below line to set MAC address for the Ethernet port
>
> setenv ethaddr E4:1E:0A:10:12:33

The U-Boot command **setenv** simply assigns a value (actually a null-terminated text string) to an environment variable.

However U-Boot handles the **ethaddr** environment variable in a special manner. The MAC address assigned to this environment variable is also written to the Ethernet PHY.
Hence this MAC address is *persistent* on this Ethernet interface even after U-Boot jumps to the Linux kernel.
When the MAC address has already been written to the PHY by U-Boot, the Linux kernel does not have to perform any MAC address initialization.

U-Boot has the **ipaddr** environment variable to assign an IPV4 address to its (active) Ethernet interface. This **ipaddr** environment variable is only useful for U-Boot's network stack while performing network operations with U-Boot. This **ipaddr** environment variable, like all of U-Boot's (non-special) environment variables, has meaning only while U-Boot is executing, and is lost when the Linux kernel is booted.

> is it possible to use the same command (setenv) to the set IP and the nesmask as well?

The U-Boot command **setenv** simply assigns a value (actually a null-terminated text string) to an environment variable.

Environment variables and configuration of the network stack in U-Boot do not persist after U-Boot transfers control to the Linux kernel. The Linux kernel needs to perform its own setup of the Ethernet interface and a network stack. If you want to pass network configuration information from U-Boot to the Linux kernel, then you could use the **bootargs** environment variable.

The conventional method of passing information from U-Boot to the Linux kernel is through the **bootargs** environment variable, which (can) be used to compose the kernel command line. The **bootargs** could be hardcoded in the source at buildtime, or this environment variable could be constructed at boot-time using the  **setenv** command. For details of how **bootargs** can become the kernel command line with an ARM Linux kernel, see [How to set Linux kernel command line on ARM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68307458/how-to-set-linux-kernel-command-line-on-arm/68340492#68340492).

Note that the contents of **bootargs**, when used as the kernel command line, is intended for the kernel, and not userspace. A userspace program can access/read this command line (e.g. in the **/proc/cmdline** file), but that is not the purpose of the command line.

Instead of simply trying to pass network configuration information, you can instruct the kernel to initialize the network interface using the `ip=` boot parameter in the command line (via the **bootargs** variable). See [how to bring network up at boot time in linux](https://superuser.com/questions/502793/how-to-bring-network-up-at-boot-time-in-linux)